# adding gsap timeline to parent react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I have a couple of React components using GSAP for entrance animations. As an example, I have an `ImageReveal` component that does a nice swiping animation on load.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { gsap } from 'gsap';

import s from './ImageReveal.scss';

interface ImageProps {
  src: string;
  alt?: string;
  className?: string;
  imageRef?: string;
}

export const ImageReveal = ({ src, alt, className }: ImageProps) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const swipeRef = useRef(null);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: 'Power2.easeInOut' } });

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.to(containerRef.current, { css: { visibility: 'visible' }, duration: 0 })
      .fromTo(
        swipeRef.current,
        { height: '100%' },
        {
          height: '0%',
          duration: 1.4,
          clearProps: 'height',
        },
      )
      .from(imageRef.current, { scale: 1.6, duration: 1.4, delay: -1.6 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={s(s.imageReveal, className)} ref={containerRef}>
      <div className={s.imageReveal__swipe} ref={swipeRef} />
      <img src={src} alt={alt} ref={imageRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, I'm wanting to use this component's timeline within the context of a parent component's timeline. So, for example, if i have an `ImageHero` component with a timeline of it's own, and I'm using the `ImageReveal` component inside the grid, is there a way that i can utilize this timeline within my `ImageHero`, or any other similar use case, so that I'm not having to write a timeline each time I want to use my `ImageReveal` component? Here, also, is my `ImageHero` so you can see what I'm talking about.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { HeadingReveal } from 'components/heading-reveal/HeadingReveal';
import { ImageReveal } from 'components/image-reveal/ImageReveal';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';

import s from './ImageHero.scss';

interface ImageHeroProps {
  slice: any;
}

export const ImageHero = ({ slice }: ImageHeroProps) => {
  const gridRef = useRef(null);
  const headingRef = useRef(null);

  const tl = gsap.timeline({ delay: 0.5, defaults: { ease: 'Power4.easeInOut', duration: 1 } });

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.to(gridRef.current, { css: { visibility: 'visible' }, duration: 0 }).from(
      headingRef.current,
      { y: 80 },
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={s.imageHero} ref={gridRef}>
      <div className={s.imageHero__container}>
        {slice.primary.heading && (
          <HeadingReveal tag="h1" className={s.imageHero__heading} headingRef={headingRef}>
            {slice.primary.heading.text}
          </HeadingReveal>
        )}
        {slice.items.map((content: any, index: number) => {
          return (
            <ImageReveal
              src={content.image.url}
              className={s.imageHero__image}
              key={`image-${index}`}
              alt={content.image.alt}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I created a very minimal CodeSandbox for anyone with code examples. Thank you so much!

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-tdd-04qz5

Comment: You can pass a timeline in the same way that you pass any variable from child component to parent component. [One example here](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25688-react-sharing-timeline-throught-multiple-components/?do=findComment&comment=124632). Side notes: use .set() instead of a zero duration tween. You don't need the css: {} wrapper. And your ease should be `ease: 'power4.inOut'`

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm newish to React still, would you have a chance to clarify a specific code implementation for my use case based on the link? Seems very viable! Thanks so much!

Comment: I think it'd be easiest for me or someone else to help give you the correct code if you made a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using something like a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Edited my question to include a sandbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much of a React user, so there might be a better way to set things up (like not making your `useEffect`s reliant on the timelines and the function) but I got it working this way: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-frost-nkuj9?file=/src/components/image-grid/ImageGrid.js

I used format from [the forum thread I referenced in the comments](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25688-react-sharing-timeline-throught-multiple-components/?do=findComment&comment=124632) and applied it to your situation.